# Symfony 4.1 application redirectes to an external URL in another machine

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to test a **Symfony** 4.1 application on my machine from the production server . I copied all the files in the **www** folder and copied the database . The problem is that when I test the application on my **test server** it redirects automatically to the **production server** (The original server) which means that I cant test and make changes to the test application . The application was created by an external  developper .
I was wondering if you could help me find the file which does the redirect. many thanks

Comment: It's hard to be specific without knowing more details. But some starting points to ask yourself - what server am I running? Let's say it's Apache - is there a `.htaccess` file? Is there a hardcoded redirect rule in there etc. Short of this, you will have to elaborate on your question with more details about your development environment etc.

Comment: its a wamp server on both servers , but about the .htaccess  I am not sure , the application is quite big and I am new in Symfony, where do we have put the the .htaccess file to make such redirect ?

Comment: It sounds like you are running Apache, so it's worth checking the contents of the `.htaccess` file, if one is present. Assuming your project is open in some kind of code editor, go to the `public/` dir (it should contain an `index.php` file amongst others). Is there a `.htaccess` file there? If so, open it and search for the production server domain name to see if there is some sort of hard-coded redirect in there.

Comment: this is the .htaccess I found in the public directory , it does seem to have anything hard coded in it .

Comment: <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

   
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

   
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I'd start looking in your controllers next. Save yourself some time and grep (or use your code editor) to search for the domain name inside the `src/` directory.

Comment: </IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

Comment: I have searched the entire src folder , there is no file that contains the redirect to the server . It seems I have to contact the developper first

Comment: `# When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of the start page to the front controller explicitly` - sounds like your answer

Comment: what should I do then , it says RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/ that does not make sense to me?

Comment: There's not a lot I can do to assist at this stage - but have a look inside `public/index.php` and look at all the controllers located in `src/Controllers` to see if there is some code that is doing this redirect (as suggested by the comment in the .htaccess file)

Comment: I have found a similar issue posted here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90720/is-a-masked-307-redirect-for-a-domain-possible I will try to follow on that

Comment: If it s not too much to ask , when you migrate from the production server towards the test server you only move the files from www into your directory and export the database and then link them up ? is that how how it is done ?

Comment: This could be the case but it probably isn't right for me to speculate because I don't know anything about the setup of your environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the vhosts config file.  It contained the redirect to the public folder